# How to display an alert when form is successfully posted using PHP and jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

jQuery modal is executed fine, but I don't know what am I missing when I want to display an alert message when the form is successfully executed by php?

```
$.post(
    'name.php', 
    { ime: ime, location: location }, 
    function(data){                     
        if (data.success) {
            alert("form posted!");
        }
        else {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        } 
    },
    "json"
);
```

==========================The PHP============

```
if ($result == false) {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'result' => 0));
    exit;
}

echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'result' => $result));
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM $names WHERE name='$ime'";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: Check the response in your console to ensure the data is coming back as you expect.

Comment: I have posted the results from the Console below.

Answer (score 2):

Looks as if the value of `data.success` is not coming back as true or false (or evaulating as a boolean like you're expecting).

Try:

```
$.post(
 'name.php', 
 { ime: ime, location: location }, 
function(data){                     
    if (data.success == 'true') {
        alert("form posted!");
    }
    else {
        $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    } 
},
"json"
```

);

You could also use `FIDDLER` to see the value coming back from the server.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Changed the code according to yours. If record doesn't exist in the DB in the Console I get: **result: 0, success: false**.

If it does exists in the console I get this: **{"success":true,"result":["67","John","London"]}**

Still doesn't alert, just executes the query.

Answer (score 1):

the success has 3 argument `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`

I believe you may want `textStatus`

```
.success:
```

> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter; **a string describing the status**;
>   and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

```
$.post(
    'name.php', 
    { ime: ime, location: location }, 
    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                     
        if (textStatus == "success") {
            alert("form posted!");
        }
        else {
            $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
        } 
    },
    "json"
);
```